# Counting and summing with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, sum

I have the following dataframe.

```
Name <- c("John","Mark","Ella","Mike","Zedd","John","Maria","Nick","John","Nick","Zedd","Andrea")
Age <- c(16,25,45,23,26,28,19,20,43,31,33,15)
df <- data.frame(Name,Age)
```

I want to group by name and sum the years of age. This what I am using without success.

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Years = sum(Age)), count = count(Name))
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Age = sum(Age))
` ?

Comment: Yes, but i want the count how many times each name appeards

Comment: You can use `n()`, Peter's answer should give you that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
library(dplyr

df <- data.frame(Name,Age) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(Years = sum(Age, rm.na = TRUE),
            count = n())
```